# How to use Struct as Observer in NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift4, notificationcenter

In NotificationCenter Class , Why apple has created Observer of type Any?

```
func addObserver(Any, selector: Selector, name: NSNotification.Name?, object: Any?)
```

My Reasoning.

1. If observer is struct then on assigning inside as function parameter, It will be copied then how my observer can receive the notification.
2. I can't write any function which uses @objc prefix in Struct.
3. Selector is always be type of @objc.

So What is the use of Any in addObserver.....
It should always be of type AnyObject.

Secondly we already known that NotificationCenter keep the weak copy of observer, And we can't use weak modifier for type Any. Then how apple is managing all this?

Any help in understanding this concept is highly appreciated.

Comment: Answer for all of your questions is Objective C, in objective c there no such type as Swift struct, so to be able to interact with it you should use Swift classes)

Comment: Yes I know in ObjectiveC there are no Swift Structs , So apple should use AnyObject instead of Any. It confuses with the fact that Any is for both reference and value type. So how can I use value type here.

Answer (score 0):

No one chose to make this parameter `Any`. It's just what they got by default. It's automatically bridged from ObjC:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)observer 
        selector:(SEL)aSelector
        name:(nullable NSNotificationName)aName
        object:(nullable id)anObject;
```

The default way that `id` is bridged is `Any`. It hasn't been specially refined for Swift. In practice, you can't really use structs meaningfully here. The fact that the compiler won't stop you from calling it in an unhelpful way doesn't imply that it's intended to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why type `Any?` - because in Objective C it is type `id`.

Why you can't mark your function as `@obj` - `@obc` is the keyword for Swift code which indicates what compiler should add this method to a header file for this **Class**, yes you can make headers only for **Classes**.

Selector also is the objective-c term, it just says which function to invoke, similar to `msg_send`

Answer (score 0):

> In NotificationCenter Class , Why apple has created Observer of type Any.

Because *all* Objective-C `id` declarations are translated into Swift as Any.

You might object that this really should be AnyObject, because only a class will work here. And indeed, that's the way `id` used to be translated into Swift. But nowadays you can pass anything where an `id` is expected, because if it's something Objective-C can't understand, it will be boxed up as a class instance (e.g. as a `_SwiftValue`) so that it can make the round-trip into Objective-C and back again to Swift. Therefore `id` is translated as Any.

However, just because you *can* pass a struct here doesn't mean you should. It won't work, as you've discovered. Objective-C cannot introspect a Swift struct.

There are *lots* of situations like this, where Cocoa gives you enough room to hang yourself by passing the wrong thing. The `contents` of a CALayer is typed as Any, but if you pass anything other than a CGImage, nothing will happen. The `layerClass` if a UIView is typed as AnyClass, but you'd better pass a CALayer subclass. I could go on and on.